# Python How to get a integer using the ord function?

Tags: python, function, sum, digits

I am having trouble with my code the main issue is I want to return 1 by using the getEquivalentNumber function but the problem is that when I run the code it gives me the result of -63 is there any way for me to improve the code to get a better result.

```
print('*' * 50)
user_input = input('Please enter a word. \n'
               '-->')
print('*' * 50)




def getEquivalentNumber(_Mychar):
    _Mychar = _Mychar.lower()
    equivalentNumber = ord(_Mychar) - 96

    return equivalentNumber



def computeSumOfCharacters(myWord):
    sum = 0
    for i in myWord:  # apple
        sum += getEquivalentNumber(i)

    return sum


print(computeSumOfCharacters(user_input))
```

Comment: What is it that's confusing? You need to provide more information; show us an attempt. Do you know what a function is for example? Then **b** should be no problem. You need to explain what is confusing as we can't just solve the assignment for you.

Comment: What part of it is confusing?  Do you know how to get started?

Comment: It's OK to ask homework questions, but you need to give it a shot yourself and ask about your solution, don't ask people on here to solve it for you https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Yes I can definitely show you guys an example my apologies for the confusion I forgot to add in my code.

Comment: print('*' * 50)
user_input = input('Please enter a word. \n'
                   '-->')
print('*' * 50)


def getEquivalentNumber(_Mychar):
    _Mychar = _Mychar.lower()
    equivalentNumber = ord(_Mychar) - 96

    return equivalentNumber


def computeSumOfCharacters(myWord):
    sum = 0
    for i in myWord:  # apple
        sum += getEquivalentNumber(i)

    return sum

def computeSumOfDigits(myNumber):
    list = [int(x) for x in str(sum)]
    total = 0
    for i in range(0, len(list)):
        total = total + int(list[i])
    print('The magic number for \' total)

Comment: You need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30013828) the code into the question. We can't read code in comments.

Comment: I edited the code in the question you should be able to see it now

Comment: A bit quick on the trigger with closing the question, if OP says they are willing to add the code... @TheAustinator - you haven't made clear what exactly confuses you.  You're not calling your functions, are you unclear on how to use functions? Also, your indentation is a mess - please remember that in Python, indentation means something and you may end up with mysteriously broken code if you don't consistently indent it.

Comment: I edited the question I don't know why it closed I wanted to fix it so that way it didn't look like I wasn't trying.

Comment: Refer my comment - your code has syntax problems, and you didn't clearly explain what your actual problem / question is. "Confused" is very generic. However, I agree that it was closed a bit hastily (3 votes to close is enough, that's how it works)

Comment: You are right I will resubmit my question and I will try to reword it the best I can

Comment: I redid the question because I accidently sent the wrong code I hope this explains it better.

Answer (score 1):

1. You define functions with `def`.
2. You can get the value of the units digit of a number with `number % 10`.
3. You can *remove* the units digit with `number = number // 10`.
4. You can accumulate those digits by starting an accumulator at zero and adding each digit.
5. You can loop until the number becomes zero.
6. You can return a value from the function with `return`.

Apologies if some of that seems too basic but I'm not sure what skill level you're at. That's pretty much the process I'd follow, without giving you the actual code.

---

The only thing that concerns me is `computeSumOfDigits(911) must return a SINGLE digit` yet the text after that says `9 + 1 + 1 = 11`.

If you are required to further process results that are not a single digit, you can check that before returning and call the same function on the result, something like (pseudo-code):

```py
if accumulator > 9:
    return computeSumOfDigits(accumulator)
```

That would calculate: `9 + 1 + 1 -> 11, 1 + 1 -> 2`.